# Creating an asana task with asana api gives invalid identifier error

Tags: javascript, asana-api

MY Payload looks like this.

```
var data={
                  "workspace":"1234",
                   "name": task_name ,
                   "notes":striped_msg ,
                   "memberships":[
                     {
                       "project":678,
                        "section":111
                      },
                     {
                       "project":1230
                     }
                   ],
                    "custom_fields":{
                       "303093523672299":"303093523672300"
                        },
                       "due_on":string_date
                     }
```

sending the payload like this.

```
 var status = await asanaService.addTask(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Getting the following error in response

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not interpret {\"workspace\":"1234",\"name\":\"rohit as an identifier in {\"workspace\":"1234",\"name\":\"rohit.one [ Mysql cpu ]\",\"notes\":..............","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Missing the JSON header during post

Comment: can you write it all here?